# .screenrc and logging in to multiple remote servers

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gnu-screen, screenrc

I'm looking for a way to login into multiple remote servers using SSH on multiple tabs while using screen. Now I have set multiple tabs when running my screen and bash on each of it and I have to manually connect to each remote server using SSH and enter the password for my key. Now I'm looking for a way to enter that password once and login to all of servers automatically. All of them are possible to login using same ssh key. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `ssh-agent` to store your key in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a way to - do the same thing on X servers. If you are on ubuntu you can achieve the same using [terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/). Open up terminator, split the screen X times and then start the broadcast mode in the left top corner of the screen. This will allow you to work like a jedi!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not using X, I just want to connect remotely to one of remote servers and then connect to a number of another remote servers to have it on tabs in screen.